# Is it possible to fix a section of buffer fixed on top even when scrolling?

Tags: split, vimdiff, filenames

I need to open 4 different files on my screen to consolidate data on diff file .
I kept forgetting which tile is which file..
All my files has file name on line 1..
Is there way to keep the line 1 fixed? So that when i scroll around the file the title of each file to stay on top for easy identification instead of click on the file to view the file name on windows frame (window title bar).

Comment: Have you checked [`:h 'statusline'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27statusline%27)? With something like this for example `set statusline+=[\%t\]` you get the file name in the statusbar for all your files

Comment: @statox with the default `'laststatus'` of `1`, the default `'statusline'` (which includes the name of the file in the buffe) should show, no?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes probably, I was to lazy to check the default values :) And I should have mentioned `laststatus` in my comment :+1:

Comment: Glad we agree; my comment was also partly for the OP—perhaps something has been changed from the default?

Comment: Were you guys mentioning the statusline (the line under the vim terminal), i have that. However because i cramp 4 buffer file into a screen, it is too narrow to display the file name, hence truncated.. the statusline currently shows : truncated filename [utf-8, unix][text] Line:**/****[1%] col:*** Buf:* [***][0x**] .  I won't be able to tell which file is which with truncated filename.

Comment: you can also put it on the tabline